# jquery fading between to blockquotes

Tags: jquery, slider, fade

I have 2 blockquotes and just want to use jquery to implement a continuous fade between them at about 10seconds.

Can this be achieved with jquery.

Comment: Yes possible.Can you please show some codes.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('#firstQuote').fadeTo(200, 0.8);
setInterval(function(){
    $('blockquote').filter(':visible').fadeOut(1000,function(){
        if($(this).next('blockquote').size()){
            $(this).next().fadeTo(1000, 0.8);
        }
        else{
            $('blockquote').eq(0).fadeTo(1000, 0.8);
        }
    });
},10000);
```

});